# actionscript error?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a problem, this works then at the " and" it dies and gives me an error

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access
>   a property or method of a null object
>   reference.    at
>   Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/frameLooper()
>     at
>   flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
>     at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

CODE

```
var string:String = "Welcome to PuppetWeb Inc\nMy name is Steve and I will be your host for this presentation!\n...\nOkay I think it is ready, let's go!";
var myArray:Array = string.split("");
var timer : Timer = new Timer (100, myArray.length);
timer.addEventListener (TimerEvent.TIMER, frameLooper);
timer.start();

function frameLooper(event:Event):void {
    if(myArray.length > 0) {
        text1.appendText(myArray.shift());
    }else{
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameLooper);
    }
}
```

It works for the start and then just dies at and, and then it shows that error about 50 times and restarts.

Any help?

Comment: It's been too long since I've used as3 to confidently provide an answer, but shouldn't that be `timer.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameLooper);` instead of `removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameLooper);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is code written on a keyframe in the timeline, so my guess would be that your textfield goes away for some reason, most likely a keyframe animation of some kind.

It's also somewhat odd that you are removing an `Event.ENTER_FRAME` listener when the array is empty and not the `TimerEvent.TIMER`

Comment: That, plus he's not removing the listener from the timer he added it too.

Answer (score 1):

At the end, you're trying to remove the listener from an implicit "this". Your statement is equivalent to:

```
this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameLooper);
```

But "this" is a reference to the main timeline (if this is a frame script on the main timeline) or a reference to the instance that contains this code. It's **not** a reference to the Timer instance, which is what you need:

```
event.target.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, frameLooper);
```

Comment: removing an enter_frame listener from a timer makes no sense.

Comment: Couldn't you just utilize closures and save yourself the work of dealing with `event.target`?

Comment: @grapefrukt- I edited it to change the event type also, I read right past that (saw what I expected to see, not what was there!) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use string.charAt()?

```
var string:String = "Welcome to PuppetWeb Inc\nMy name is Steve and I will be your host for this presentation!\n...\nOkay I think it is ready, let's go!";
var timer : Timer = new Timer (100, string.length);
timer.addEventListener (TimerEvent.TIMER, frameLooper);
timer.start();

function frameLooper(event:TimerEvent):void {
    text1.appendText(string.charAt (event.target.currentCount-1);
}
```

Comment: And btw you don't need to remove that ENTER_FRAME listener, because you never add one. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Among all the other issues Stated in the other posts you are not stopping the time.
Dont forget `timer.stop( );`